# iPhone Screen Press Detection

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to build an app that detects if a user puts their lips on the screen.  How could I get an image of their lips when they put it on the screen?

I know how to detect finger touches, would it be similar to that?

**Edit:  Also, wondering about doing this for Android.**

Comment: I would invite you to flesh the question out a bit more. a) how would you know it was lips and not six or seven fingers? b) what would you do to determine if someone was touching their lips to paper besides the obvious of "I would see it" ... think powder and a nose print besides the lips

Comment: @drachenstern +1 for powder and nose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have posted here, it is not possible to detect all of the contact points of the lips and the screen. Yes, it would be similar, but more difficult. The iPhone screen is capacitive, so it should detect lips, which are similar to fingertips. (When outside in the cold and I need to scroll with my gloves on, I've used my chin.)

As far as the shape, you may be able to map multiple touches, but touches don't take on any particular shape, so you won't be able to draw the lips based on that. You may want to consider preloading generic pictures of lips and then resizing it to match the size of their lips, depending on where the touch inputs are.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the iphone hardware supports somewhere between 10 and 20 touch points, but the SDK  only gives you access to 5. To get a good outline of the lips you'd need a much higher number of touch points.

Could you use the front facing camera and avoid the obvious hygiene issues?!

Answer (score 4):

You can't get the form of the touches, so you wouldn't be able to detect lips on the screens.

Comment: But you can use the locations of the touches to perhaps map out lips

Comment: That's what I was thinking.  Maybe mapping it out.

Comment: @Moshe: I did a test by kissing my iPad (something everyone should do from time to time), I'm not sure, but I couldn't guess from two wiggling touches that they were actually my lips. Probably I have too small lips? Should I get a surgery?

Comment: I'm not telling you if you should, but I would call it dedication if you got surgery just for development purposes.

Comment: @Moshe: I looked at the prices for a surgery and decided that buying a new iMac from the money is more dedication into development than new lips.